# I want to add and remove class when URL having nav tabs id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have added Bootstrap's nav-tabs to my project. I was able to add logic that adds current tab's ID to URL.

Now I would like for my JS to activate tab on page load, based on ID provided by URL parameter/hash.

The problem I am getting now it just picking up the last if condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if ("url:contains('features#standard-features')") {
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item0 a").attr("class", "nav-link cvxcvxc active");
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item1 a , .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item2 a ,  .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item3 a").removeClass("active");
  }
  if ("url:contains('features#optional-design-features-accesories')") {
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item1 a").attr("class", "nav-link cvxcvxc active");
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item0 a , .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item2 a ,  .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item3 a").removeClass("active");
  }

  if ("url:contains('features#benefits-of-steel-structures')") {
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item2 a").attr("class", "nav-link cvxcvxc active");
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item0 a , .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item1 a ,  .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item3 a").removeClass("active");
  }
  if ("url:contains('features#optional-roof-and-wall-panels')") {
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item3 a").attr("class", "nav-link cvxcvxc active");
    $(".features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item0 a , .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item1 a ,  .features_tab_nav .feat_nav_item2 a").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you declare var url at first then why you using string "url:contains('')" ??

try this :

```
if(url.indexOf("features#standard-features") > -1){
// your code
}
```

Comment: yup its working, but why url.contains not working ?

Comment: Because you had written it as string "url:contains.." every thing in js which surrounded by "" or '' is string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using string in if condition. It should be like following:

```
if (url.contains('features#standard-features')) {
}
```

Or you can use included method:

```
if (url.includes('features#standard-features')) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every if statement gets executed, because you're giving it a string which converts to true by the engine. Try if(url.contains("whatever")) ...

Answer (score 0):

Other explained why it did not work.

Here is a simpler way using the actual hash

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash) hash = hash.slice(1); // remove the leading "#"
  const $nav = $(".features_tab_nav").removeClass("active");

  const idx = ["standard-features", "optional-design-features-accesories", "benefits-of-steel-structures", "optional-roof-and-wall-panels"].indexOf(hash);
  if (idx=== -1) idx =  0; // default 0
  $nav.eq(idx).addClass("active"))
});
```